# Solr Nested Faceting with Filtering facets

Tags: solr, facet

In my solr index, i have a field tag with the following definition.

```
<field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

I already have a predefined list of tags (a, b, c, d, e) with me and i want to do nested faceting only for those tags.

```
top_tags:{
    type: terms,
    field: tags,
    limit: 5,
    facet:{
        type: terms,
        field: tags,
        limit: 5
    }
  }
```

when i apply above nested faceting, it gives me nested faceting output for top 5 tags instead of giving for my predefined tags. following is the output.

```
"top_tags":{
      "buckets":[{
          "val":"x",
          "count":10,
          "buckets":[
          {
            "val":"x",
            "count":10
          },
          {
                "val":"y",
                "count":5
         }
        ]}},
```

How can i apply filtering logic (something like facet query) on top of json nested faceting ?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use facet queries?

Comment: @MatsLindh sure, i can. i know how to use facet queries in general but do not know if we can do that using json facet API. Is it possible to use facet queries with json facet API.